# Disable prettier for a single file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, prettier

I need to disable **prettier** for a *single file* (API URLs file) in my project in Vs-code. actually, I need each API and its URL to be in one line, but prettier breaks them in two lines.

**before**

```
export const GET_SEARCH_TEACHERS = params => myexampleFunction_app_base(`teachers/search/${params.search}`);
```

**after**

```
export const GET_SEARCH_TEACHERS = params =>
myexampleFunction_app_base(`teachers/search/${params.search}`);
```

Comment: May you post an example of what's happening?

Comment: You might want to consult the documentation for questions like this. https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3634

Comment: based documentation you've mentioned there is a package 'Formatting Toggle' for vs code for do this , But I prefer not to install the new package.

Comment: The github link mentions that ignoring a single file in VSCode is not trivial, so someone made an extension for it. If you don't want to install it, you'll likely need to implement your own.

Comment: Or you could use a "prettier ignore" comment which will ignore those lines from being formatted

Comment: an example added.

Comment: Can you give an example with prettier ignore or share a link that describe that with example

Comment: I already have (please check the links in the comment above)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you want a certain file in a repo to never be formatted by prettier, you can add it to a .prettierignore file: [Disable Prettier for one file](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#ignoring-files)

From the docs:

> To exclude files from formatting, create a .prettierignore file in the
> root of your project. .prettierignore uses [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) syntax.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> # Ignore artifacts: 
> build 
> coverage
>
> # Ignore all HTML files:
> *.html
> ```

Comment: and if you want to disable the whole thing just put ** in the prettierignore file

Comment: How can I disable single file without touching .prettierignore?

Comment: by adding this on top of your file - /* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */

Answer (score 57):

Thanks to *evolutionxbox*, so far couple of solutions were found.

## Ignoring Files or Folders

To exclude files from formatting, add entries to a `.prettierignore` file in the project `root` or set the `--ignore-path` CLI option. `.prettierignore` uses gitignore syntax.

```js
/app/src/scripts/example.js
/app/src/folder/
```

## Ignore based on extension

To exclude files based on extesntion you can add entries to a `.prettierignore` file as well

```js
*.html.erb
```

## Ignore lines

##### ***JavaScript***

A JavaScript comment of `// prettier-ignore` will exclude the next node in the abstract syntax tree from formatting.

```js
    matrix(
      1, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0,
      0, 0, 1
    )

    // prettier-ignore
    matrix(
      1, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0,
      0, 0, 1
    )
```

will be transformed to:

```js
    matrix(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1);

    // prettier-ignore
    matrix(
      1, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0,
      0, 0, 1
    )
```

##### JSX

```
    <div>
      {/* prettier-ignore */}
      <span     ugly  format=''   />
    </div>
```

more: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

## Using an extension

We can use an extension to toggle formatting like prettier on the specific page when you need it.

**Formatting Toggle**
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tombonnike.vscode-status-bar-format-toggle

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to use the prettier block-like toggle, to disable formatting for a "block" within a file.
For example, adding `// prettier-ignore` before the start of a function definition, will disable prettier formatting for that function.
Similarly, if you put the line above an `if` statement, only the if block is ignored.

Basically a block is denoted by a pair of `{` `}` matching braces.

```
... (code up here is formatted by prettier)

// prettier-ignore
function noPrettierFormattingInHere(){
  ...
}

... (code down here is formatted by prettier)
```

Answer (score 5):

create .prettierignore file in the root of your repo and add the name of the folders that you want to ignore and add full path of the file that you want to ignore and save it.

use the .gitignore format to update your file
you can read about it in the prettier website too https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#ignoring-files

Answer (score 1):

. prettierignore for React project

```
build/
node_modules/
internals/generators/
internals/scripts/
package-lock.json
yarn.lock
package.json
coverage
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this at the top of your file:

`/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */`

Answer (score 0):

To disable Prettier for a specific file just add the following code

```
// prettier-ignore
```

Example:

```
const { gql } = require("@apollo/client");

// prettier-ignore

export const INSERT_RECHARGE_REGISTER = gql`

`
```

Comment: This only disables prettier for the next statement or block.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio Code and want to save a single file without adding anything to the `.prettierignore` or to the file itself, simply save the file using this shortcut:

`CTRL + K CTRL + SHIFT + S`