# How to disable Prettier for a Dart-generated JavaScript import?

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

I'm using the Dart language to generate JavaScript code, which I then import into my project. However, when I import the generated JavaScript file, my ESLint setup throws Prettier-related errors, even though the code formatting doesn't affect its execution. I want to disable Prettier for this specific import to avoid these errors.

i have been try disable but nothing work.

Comment: basically you are asking how to disable prettier for js files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable prettier for a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59876638/disable-prettier-for-a-single-file)